# Views relatonship with multi value field - and views distinct

Tags: views, nodes

I have a View that shows a list of Classes (nodes) and the relevant Teachers (Users) on my system. It is designed to show one class per table row and then a comma seperated list of the users who belong to this class.

As my "relationship" in the View is a user reference field (multi valued) then I get a list of Classes and teachers names next to them (as this uses the relationship to find Profile2 fields of First Name, Surname etc). But it causes duplicate nodes. I have tried using Views Distinct but you can see what happens below. I can get rid of the duplicates but it doesn't give any way for me to have a comman seperated list of my rewrote ouput of Users.

[image]

In my example there are 3 users referencing "Year 2" but when I try to eliminate the duplicates - it only shows one teacher next to that class. Is there a way around this duplicate, multi valued, relationship issue in Views?

Answer (score 0):

use group-by class so it will show you unique class name with teachers for the class

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Bala I think it might be an answer posted in good faith. It rings some bells to me. Sadly I don't understand it, but it *"sounds"* not entirely unlike things I encountered playing with Views grouping.

Comment: Grouping does not resolve by issue as this would change the layout into seperate tables where the header is a "Class Name" - thanks for suggestion though